# how to bundle cases for "data-" attributes in a switch statement?

Tags: javascript, variables, switch-statement, case

I'm running a switch statement with fairly many cases handling `data-attributes`.

Currently I'm stuck with this:

```
switch(attribute) { 
    case "value":
    case "data-vv-validations":
    case "data-relation":
    case "data-tolerance":
    case "data-theme":
    case "type":
    case "readonly":
    case "size":
      if (setters[attribute]) {
        element.setAttribute(attribute, setters[attribute]);
      }
    break;
 }
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to combine all `data-` attributes into a single `case`, because listing all possible options I'm running into is kind of "not generic"...

**Question:**
In CSS selectors I can do somethink like `[class*=" ui-icon-"]`. Can I also make the `case` value more generic?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to accept ANY data-*, or some of them that you know in advance?

Comment: What is it you want to do with this switch case exactly? Couldn't you just leave out the switch case and only do the setters[attribute] check?

Comment: @jgroenen: nope. I'm generating elements and setting properties. The switch above is for all properties requiring logic, such as whether an input is `readonly` or an option is `selected`. See [here](https://gist.github.com/frequent/6583140)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of. You can see if the first characters are `"data-`, and if so, just use those chars for the switch.

```
var a = attribute.slice(0, 5) === "data-" ? "data-" : attribute;

switch(a) { 
    case "value": case "data-": case "type": case "readonly": case "size":
      if (setters[attribute]) {
        element.setAttribute(attribute, setters[attribute]);
      }
    break;
 }
```

This reduces all `data-` attributes to a single testable value. Note that you still use the full `attribute` with the `setters[]`.

---

Or since you already seem to have the attribute names in a `setters` map, you could just do this:

```
if (setters[attribute]) {
    element.setAttribute(attribute, setters[attribute]);
}
```

Your `switch` seemed to be redundant since you were almost performing the same test when you do this:

```
if (setters[attribute]) {
```

---

Or if you need to test specifically the name, then...

```
if (setters.hasOwnProperty(attribute) && setters[attribute]) {
```

Comment: @frequent: See my update. Your `switch` statement seems a little redundant.

Comment: I do have more cases than that with different things to run

Comment: @frequent: Oh, OK. That makes more sense then.

Comment: I don't think this is good code. It uses some accidental patterns (which may change over time) in a set of identifiers to solve the problem. If you think the other solutions add "too much overhead", then I would suggest changing your html, adding an attribute to these "special" nodes: <div data-whatever="special"></div>

Comment: @jgroenen: Describe what you mean by *"accidental patterns (which may change over time) in a set of identifiers"*

Comment: @Pato asked: "You need to accept ANY data-\*, or some of them that you know in advance?". Since there was no answer to that, you may not assume that you can ignore data-\* in general (because you know "assumption is the mother of all f\*\*\*-ups).

Comment: @jgroenen: I don't know how I would be ignoring data- attributes in general. This will accept *any* data- attributes. And there's no assumption being made about the requirement. The last sentence in the question clearly states that a generic solution is desired, which is what this is. Furthermore, the code does have a constraint with `if (setters[attribute]) {`

Comment: I don't see exactly what the switch case is adding to the if statement.

Comment: @jgroenen: You'll notice that I address that in my answer as well. And OP clarified the need for the `switch` in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829038/how-to-bundle-cases-for-data-attributes-in-a-switch-statement/18829162?noredirect=1#comment27775408_18829162)

Answer (score 1):

Simply solved with something like this:

```
var attributeSwitch = attribute.indexOf("data-") == 0 ? "data-*" : attribute;

case(attributeSwitch){
    case "value":
    case "data-*":
    case "type":
    case "readonly":
    case "size":
      if (setters[attribute]) {
        element.setAttribute(attribute, setters[attribute]);
      }
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't make "generic case statements".
But you can use an array of possible values and then check if the value is one of those.

```
function inArray(array, value) {
    for(var i=0, len=array.length; i<len; i++) {
        if(array[i] == value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var possibleValues = ["value", 
                     "data-vv-validations", 
                     "data-relation", 
                     "data-tolerance", 
                     "data-theme", 
                     "type", 
                     "readonly", 
                     "size"];

if (setters[attribute] && inArray(possibleValues, attribute)) {
    element.setAttribute(attribute, setters[attribute]);
}
```